# How to port pytest environment to AWS testvm

Tags: python, pytest, bamboo, portability, python-venv

I wrote a couple of pytest/Selenium tests in a new project (with `venv`) and they are working as expected. Now if I have to run these tests in another system - how can I achieve that?
The tests are put in a git repository so I can access them, but what about the Python executable and the essential Python packages like Selenium etc..? I tried googling and did not find much.

The system where I am supposed to run the tests is an AWS testvm with CLI access only and has to be accessed using `Bamboo`. What are the steps required to get the new system ready for running these tests? Do I have to create a script to be run before I run the tests in that system?

Comment: What is that "system"? Is it a local machine, or in a CI? It sounds like this is Windows, but CLI only sounds like Unix? Or is it a docker container? Do you have root access / admin rights there? Do you want to know how to install the Python environment there? We need to know a bit more of your use case to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi MrBean Bremen - The system will be a unix CLI system, it is not a local machine. It will be AWS test-vm. I have to access it through Bamboo. My local system is windows where I will be developing tests. How to make sure that the same python and packages versions are maintained in multiple systems?